# <thread>: no match for operator <

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am trying to implement mutlithreading in a C++11 program.

I separated the threading from my main program and tried to get the most basic example working:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void first_procedure() {
    std::cout << "First procedure output." << std::endl;
}

void second_procedure() {
    std::cout << "Second procedure output." << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::thread first_thread(first_procedure);
    std::thread second_thread(second_procedure);
    first_thread.join();
    second_thread.join();
    return 0;
}
```

However, even with this example, I get the following error:

> c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\thread    In function 'bool std::operator<(std::thread::id, std::thread::id)':
>
> 88    30  c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\thread  [Error] no match for 'operator<' (operand types are 'std::thread::native_handle_type {aka ptw32_handle_t}' and 'std::thread::native_handle_type {aka ptw32_handle_t}')

I am using the Orwell Dev-C++ 5.7.1 with TDM-GCC 4.7.1 64-bit on Windows 8. When calling the linker, I add -static-libgcc -std=c++11.

Edit 1: I joined the threads and get the same error message.

Comment: Note that your program is broken. You must not destroy a joinable thread.

Comment: You need to join these threads.

Comment: Is this the entire code? If so, your compiler is broken - get a new one.

Comment: I edited my post. Even if I join the threads, I get the same error message.
Yes, this is my entire code.

Comment: TDM-GCC **4.7.1**, and yet your included header is gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\ **4.8.1** \include ? I don't know how you pieced together that toolchain with chewing gum and bailing wire, but its f'ed up.

Comment: Oh yeah, @WhozCraig is right. You can't compile using the TDM-GCC compiler along with MinGW libraries - Use one, or the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was noticed in the comments first:

From your error messages and supplementary details:

```
compiler: TDM-GCC 4.7.1
includes: gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include
```

Your compiler is attempting to use libraries that are for a different compiler.
Either use `4.7.1` *or* `4.8.1`, not a mix of the two.

The good news is that your code looks fine.  Sort out the toolchain and it should compile without issue.